# Add a default using directive to ScriptCS

Tags: c#, roslyn, scriptcs

Is there a way that I can add a default using directive to ScriptCS? So when I start ScriptCS I do not need to include the namespace for classes in that namespace.

For example, I may need to interact with the [Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) within the System.Diagnostics namespace a lot. If I want to create a new instance of this class, I need to do

```
var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
```

I would rather do

```
var proc = new Process();
```

I know that I can add the using statement each time I start ScriptCS, but I would like it to always be there.

Comment: [`using` *directive*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx), not [`using` *statement*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). `using` statements's in C# are syntactic sugar for a `try`/`catch` block that calls `Dispose` on a disposable object.

Comment: thanks, I made the correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add additional assembly references and using statements into your en and by writing a [Script Pack](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/wiki/Authoring-script-packs). You can see an example of injecting using statements in the [Web API example](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs-webapi/blob/dev/src/ScriptCs.WebApi/ScriptPack.cs#L19).

Answer (score 2):

A script pack can do this as Justin mentioned. An alternative option would be to use global modules, example here (https://github.com/scriptcs-contrib/scriptcs-sample-module) however currently they don't support this nicely. If the module had a hook for getting all the services after they were created, you could do this.

I filed this bug (https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/issues/472) to allow addressing this in a much cleaner fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this can be accomplished by modifying the DefaultNamespaces property of the [ScriptExecutor class](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/blob/dev/src/ScriptCs.Core/ScriptExecutor.cs) to include the namespace you want to always have.

You would need to download [the source](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/archive/dev.zip) (or fork a new branch in github), modify and compile yourself. You would then put the new ScriptCs.Core assembly in the install folder (C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\scriptcs). This would replace the existing assembly. If you do this you will lose any changes if you are updating through [chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/)